# Can't deploy xap to windows phone 7 device using MacBook Pro

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am able to sync and manage music, pictures, etc on my samsung focus using my boot camp installation on my macbook just fine but when I try to deploy a test application to my device, I get "This operation returned because the timeout period expired" via VS2010. I get the same thing when I try to manually deploy the application using the application deployment utility.

I am able to do this fine from my dell desktop. Anyone else experienced something similar to this? Any thoughts on why this is happening?

FYI - I get the same behavior whether I am booted into boot camp or using VMWare fusion and USB pass-through.

Comment: I wouldn't know about OSX, but if you're in Windows, do you deploy via. Zune or WPConnect.exe ?

Comment: I am deploying via Zune using either VS2010 or the XapDeploy.exe

Comment: BTW - I only deploy from windows. I don't know of a way to deploy from OSX.

Comment: Try the suggestions in this thread: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/79415.aspx

Comment: keyboardP.... that fixed it. can you submit it as an answer and I'll flag it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/79415.aspx):

Try disabling the WiFi connection on your phone and deploy. If that doesn't work, try disconnecting the device and closing Visual Studio and Zune. Then reconnect the device and reopen Visual Studio.